# Chromecast synchronization protocol

Tags: synchronization, chromecast, google-cast

Is the protocol used by googlecast audio for multiplayer synchronization documented somewhere? I know the single player is here https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2, but the internet seems to be mute about the sync version

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As already announced in [Google Developers Blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/announcing-new-google-cast-apis.html) last May 2015,

> To make it easier to synchronize game state across a potentially large number of players, Google Play services 7.5 introduces the [**Cast Game Manager API**](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/gaming).

Likewise, it was stated in [Communication Model](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/gaming#model) that

> you don't have to write lots of code to keep the players and the game synchronized; the game manager does it for you.

Please try going through the given documentation for more information. Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question; the question is about the multi-room synchronization of audio not game.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to "multi-room" synchronization of Cast Audio devices across multiple speakers, that is a proprietary protocol and is not published.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's clear. I guess there is no chance even to license it?

Comment: That is not my area to answer.